# Finding Max/Min values in a linked list

Tags: linked-list

When the while loop iterates, it skips both "if" loops and when the "q=q->next" statement runs, both the max and min values are changed as well. Am I not initializing the max/min integers correctly?

```
void FindMaxMin(int& max, int& min)
    {
        NODE* q;
        q=List; //to start over
        while(q != NULL)
        {
            max=min=q->info; //Sets max and min to first value

            if(q->info>max)
                max=q->info;
            if(q->info<min)
                min=q->info;
            q=q->next;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max/min are initialized every loop cycle to the current element value. That's why ifs are skipped (since the data is neither more nor less than the actual value - it's the same).

You should write something like this to correctly initialize max/min data:

```
void FindMaxMin(int& max, int& min)
{
    NODE* q;
    q=List; //to start over
    max=min=q->info; //Sets max and min to first value
    while(q != NULL)
    {
        if(q->info>max)
            max=q->info;
        if(q->info<min)
            min=q->info;
        q=q->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow. rookie mistake. Not sure how that initialization got in the while loop! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You reset max and min to the info value of the current node for each node iteration.

Take that initialization outside of the while loop.